# new Parse.View and get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I use code from: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Todo/blob/master/js/todos.js
it has error on line: 405

```
new AppView;
```

"TypeError: undefined is not a function"
I try to debug from javascript console with

```
new Parse.View;
```

and get the same error

Comment: Make sure you include the definition of `Parse` and `Parse.View`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm already include the latest parse js ,underscore and backbone :(
Now I just replace Parse.View with Backbone.View

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok ... seems you are missing some reference.

You can check it working with absolute urls here: http://jsbin.com/sikos/2/edit

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://parseplatform.github.io/Todo/js/todos.js"></script>
```